# Ignore accents in user input

Tags: dialogflow-es

My users can type accented words in a sentence. For example they can type Ceili, ceili, Céili,céili,Ceilí, ceilí, Céilí,céilí and I require all these options to match ceili in my entity.

Is there a way to tell Dialogflow to ignore accents in user input or do I have to include all these options in the entity definition?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In Dialogflow, You have to include all the options in your entity.